# Convergence with probability 1 of an AR(1) process

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I've been working through Athreya's "Measure theory and Probability Theory" and, in chapter 7, the following exercise shows up:

---

Let $\{ X_n \}_{n = 0}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables such that for some $\rho \in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{equation*}
X_{n + 1} = \rho \cdot X_n + \varepsilon_{n + 1}, \quad n \geq 0
\end{equation*}

where $\{ \varepsilon_n \}_{n = 1}^\infty$ are independent and independent of $X_0$.

Show that if $|\rho| < 1$ and $\mathbb{E} \Big( \Big| log|\varepsilon_1| \Big| \Big) < \infty$, then

\begin{equation*}
\hat{X_n}\equiv \sum_{i = 0}^n \rho^i \cdot \varepsilon_{i + 1} \quad \text{converges with probability (w. p.)} \, 1 
\end{equation*}

to a limit $\hat{X}_{\infty}$, say.

---

My main questions are as follows:

$(i)$ Can someone provide a tip of where I can use the expected value of the log assumption?

$(ii)$ Looking at the exercise it feels that if we imposed a condition such that $\varepsilon_n$ was almost surely bounded, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it would be enough for us to prove convergence w.p. 1. Is this thought correct? Does it relate in any way to the assumption that $\mathbb{E} \Big( \Big| log|\varepsilon_1| \Big| \Big) < \infty$?

As some final remarks, I searched quite a lot within the site and most related topics discussed strategies in which the first Borel - Cantelli lemma was used, but I fail to see how I can use it under these stringent assumptions.

Thanks for all the help!

G.

Comment: The text gives the hint to show that for each $n\geqslant 1$, $X_n-\rho^n X_0$ and $\hat X_n$ have the same distribution. For $n=1$, $\hat X_1=\sum_{j=0}^1 \rho^j\varepsilon_{j+1} = \varepsilon_1 + \rho\varepsilon_2$ and $X_1-\rho X_0=\varepsilon_1$. This does not seem correct to me.